# Where can I make a web-based chatroom? No signups, nothing to download?

Tags: chat

I just want to make a group chat where nobody has to download anything or sign up for anything. I have a lot of friends across a lot of different platforms (AIM, Skype, Deviantart, Youtube) so I want something that's as openly accessible as possible.

Answer (score 9):

- **Includes Video:** [tinychat.com](http://tinychat.com)
- **Dead Simple:** [bloochat.com](http://bloochat.com)

Comment: bloochat looks perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: @madamluna, if bloochat is, indeed, perfect, remember to accept (or at least up-vote) @AlexeyMK's answer.